# Alternatives to PECL OAuth to use on ETSY APIs

Tags: php, oauth, pecl, etsy

I am building an API that will import order's information from ETSY to a proprietary back office platform.

However, while creating the OAuth connection, I got this error:
"Fatal error: Class 'OAuth' not found in..."

I did some research and apparently it is because OAuth is not enabled in my website's server. After contacting the provider (ipage) they said it is not activated in their server and it is in the pipeline of future developments.

Is there any alternative to Authenticate for ETSY?

Comment: Use any other oauth client, ie https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib

Comment: Doesnt this require installation on the server side?

Comment: what do you mean by "installation"? It's a php code. You just copy and paste it anywhere you want. Then run

Comment: I meant enabling PECL OAuth in the server where my site is hosted.

Comment: how is it related to the link I provided? It's a standalone php library that doesn't rely on pecl oauth extension